# Printing received parameters in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to print a received parameter at the end of every line... Here is what I did:

Printing info WITHOUT user:
CODE

```
user=$1
while read line; do
       linearr=($line)
       echo "${linearr[2]} ${linearr[0]} ${linearr[3]}"
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
b name2 5
c name3 2
a name1 0
```

Printing info WITH user at the end of each line:
CODE:

```
user=$1
while read line; do
       linearr=($line)
       echo "${linearr[2]} ${linearr[0]} ${linearr[3]} $user"
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
omare2 5
omare3 2
omare1 0
```

If I print the user (`echo $user`) it prints normally the name (omar)...
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `${linearr[3]}` ends with a `\r`. (`$user` could also start with that char.)

(This could happen if you're redirecting from a file with Windows-type line endings `\r\n`.)

Comment: Whats the solution to this? Is there a way to override this?